# cshtml/vbhtml and the new @ to include server side data, but without encoding?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, knockout.js

I started to learn MVC and in conjunction want to use the KnockOut.js

I am having trouble understanding why the new @ include tag encodes everything to HTML(edit: ok i know now to prevent XSS).. but even worse how to stop it from doing that..

I have this code.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    var myData = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model);
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    var initialData =  @myData ;
```

Which produces this source

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var initialData =  [{&quot;Title&quot;:&quot;Tall Hat&quot;,&quot;Price&quot;:49.95},{&quot;Title&quot;:&quot;Long Cloak&quot;,&quot;Price&quot;:78.25}] ;
```

Ok. so tried using `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode`.. and nothing happens on the included bit in the javascript because the razor engine is reencoding it? but if it use the encode then reecnodes the encodes html.. briallinat.

I cannot work out how to stop the encoding.

The msdn says use `@:` but that does not work in the javascript block, i even tried
`@{ @:new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model);}`

That just something wierd and causes other errors.

How should this be done in the MVC model?

In aspx using

`var initialData = <%= new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model) %>;`

works fine..

Comment: Try adding the script part to a ViewHelper in App_Code and making that method get @mydata as an argument

Comment: Why do you want to prevent encoding here? If I recall correctly, the content of a script tag should be encoded. At least in xhtml.

Comment: @CodeInChaos looks like it's JSON but missing the double quotes

Comment: Yea I need initial JSON data made by the server- then the rest of AJAX works fine. This only happens with razor- its the other way around to aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Html.Raw(string) will write out your string in its raw, unencoded form. Provided your string is not encoded to begin with.

code example as requested (?!?!)

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    var myData = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model);
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    var initialData =  @Html.Raw(myData) ;
```

Comment: Worked brilliant. Just take @Chris S example and provide some code.. for the next person who is less technial than me with the same question

Comment: Just for the reference, Html.Raw is in MVC3 not 2 as it just creates a new `HtmlString()`

Comment: The question was referring to specifically cshtml and vbhtml, which are the razor engine. Which is only in mvc3 +

Comment: Since the question has become so popular I have to add that this solution works but is not the recommended way of doing this. You should create a method in your controller using `JSONResult` instead of `ActionResult`. You can then populate a simple model with the data you need and simply do `Return JSON(yourModel)`. Razor will serialise the model to JSON on the fly and using jQuery the result can be Parsed to a JavaScript object with ease. Defing in AJAX that the result will be JSON will create an object on the fly too! Accessing the data will follow an object oriented model; `obj.[property]`

Answer (score 1):

MVC (or the Razor view engine in this case) encodes all your strings as a HTML string using the [MvcHtmlString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.mvchtmlstring.aspx) by default. To get around it, use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var initialData =  "@MvcHtmlString.Create(myData)";
</script>
```

This then assumes your string has already been encoded.